# Windows form c# Search button with textbox

Tags: c#, windows, forms, winforms, button

need help with to creating a search button with text box and validation boxes.

1. I can't get my CustomerArray to display on one line with tab spaces.
2. I can't bring up a validation box saying "No customer have been entered, Please enter one"). When no customer is typed into the textbox then pressed search button.

This is what I have so far for it:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string searchName = txtSearch.Text;

    for (int i = 0; i < CustomerDB.Count; i++)
    {
        string item = Convert.ToString(CustomerDB[i].GetCustomer());
        //MessageBox.Show(item);
        if (item.Contains(searchName))
        {
            index = i;
            //MessageBox.Show("index" + i);
        }
    }
    lstCustomerDB.Items.Clear();

    if (index < 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Customer not found, please try again");

    }
    else
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Customer found");
        string Customer = Convert.ToString(CustomerDB[index].GetCustomer());
        string[] CustomerArray = Customer.Split('\t');
        lstCustomerDB.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < CustomerArray.Length; i++)
        {

            lstCustomerDB.Items.Add(CustomerArray[i]);

        }


    }
}
```

Any help greatly appreaticed!

Comment: `Convert.ToString(CustomerDB[i].GetCustomer());` will return the default `"YourNamespace.Customer"` unless your `Customer` class has overridden the `ToString();` method.

Comment: ListBoxes are not the optimal control to show information on multiple columns on a single row. You should look at DataGridView.. Then that GetCustomer seems to return a string with information separated by tabs. This seems complicated and not very object oriented. Instead you should return an instance of a class Customer and manipulate it to display the  information in a DataGridView

Comment: Sorry but need to be from a listbox. But thanks!

Comment: The `index` variable needs to be reset before the search loop. E.g: `index = -1;` above the line `for (int i = 0; i < CustomerDB.Count; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

**1.**
I didn't get what's `GetCustomer()` returning exactly and why you using `Split()`. If you want your result in one line you can use `CustomerDB[index].GetCustomer().Join("\t")`

**2.**
You're trying to use `string[].Contains()` method with a `string` item here

```cs
string item = Convert.ToString(CustomerDB[i].GetCustomer());
        //MessageBox.Show(item);
        if (item.Contains(searchName))
        {
            index = i;
            //MessageBox.Show("index" + i);
        }
```

Use `Customer Object` like `Customer item = CustomerDB[i].GetCustomer()` instead

```cs
Customer item = CustomerDB[i].GetCustomer();
        //MessageBox.Show(item);
        if (item.Contains(searchName))
        {
            index = i;
            //MessageBox.Show("index" + i);
        }
```

- You can use break; to exit from foreach if you're done with finding index:

```cs
Customer item = CustomerDB[i].GetCustomer();
        //MessageBox.Show(item);
        if (item.Contains(searchName))
        {
            index = i;
            //MessageBox.Show("index" + i);
            break;
        }
```

Sgt.Panda